# Create php variable from HTML post name and value

Tags: php

I have a large HTML form posting many fields to a PHP page. I'm assigning all those fields to PHP variables one by one. Is there a way to put to create a function to auto assign the POST value to a PHP variable?

This is my code now:

```
if (!empty($_POST["x"])) {
$x = clean_post($_POST["x"]);  }  

if (!empty($_POST["y"])) {
$y = clean_post($_POST["y"]);
}?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your first question should be. Why am I you moving the data out of a perfectly good PHP array called $_POST into unnecessary scalar variables. All it does is increase my memory foot print for no good reason

Comment: If you want to clean the $_POST values do a simple `$_POST['x'] = clean($_POST['x']);`

Comment: And with that you have a way to LOOP over all the contents of `$_POST` using a simple `FOREACH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [array_keys()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function and a foreach-loop like this:

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key) {
    ${$key} = $_POST[$key];
}
```

But why not use the $_POST array in the first place?

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I'm doing some more data manipulation and find it easier to work with variables. Is there any advantage of leaving it in an array besides the memory and looping as @RiggsFolly mentioned?

Comment: @DanW. When memory and processing speed are no issues, sure, you can assign the values of your `$_POST` superglobal to variables like this, however, when working with associative arrays (like `$_POST`) I think it's better to keep those in one single place, rather than having seperate variables. It also makes your code more understandable and more readable

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's a rubbish idea. They actually had this in PHP, but removed it. It was called `register_globals`. So for instance, `$_POST['name']` would automatically have `$name` created.

If you insist on this terrible idea, you should be able to do it like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Don't do it though! Read this for more info https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php